# Mac Catalyst textview first responder

Tags: swift, uitextview, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

I've strange interface behavior when I try to implement my notes app works on Mac with Catalyst. I made textview

```
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

But after I creating new notes Catalyst in some way moves focus to back button. And after creating another textview focus works as it should.

[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swLoh.gif)

So it's rotates and I don't understand why textView.becomeFirstResponder() not works everytime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do this in an asynchronous firebox

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
     textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```